# Accessing Static ISqlConnections in Serenity .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, serenity-platform

Replaced static SqlConnections with ISqlConnections abstraction, it is now theorically possible to use dynamic connection strings per request (multi tenancy++)

In Serenity .net 5 static SqlConnections was replaced with ISqlConnections abstraction, therefore the below line of code doesn't work.

Current Helper Method:

```
  public bool SaveLoginLog(LoginLogRow logRow)
   {
  using (var connection = SqlConnections.NewFor<LoginLogRow>())
  }
```

How would I be able to access a static instance of ISqlConnections within a helper class? Similar to the above snippet of code?

Comment: Without more details about the current code and what the new one looks like there is not much help to be provided. We would be left guessing what you meant. You need to provide relevant details if you want proper help.

Comment: I've just added the method definition, it's in a helper class and I need access to a static ISqlConnections. Not sure how to describe this better, I need to resolve ASP.NET Core DI in static classes. @Nkosi

Comment: You might want to check in the documentation of the library to see if `static ISqlConnection` is a thing in it

Answer (score 1):

You may declare a static class like the following

```
public static class AppStatics
{
    public static ISqlConnections SqlConnections { get; set; }

    public static void InitializeServices(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        SqlConnections = services.GetRequiredService<ISqlConnections>();
    }
}
```

and in your Startup.cs Configure method

```
AppStatics.InitializeServices(app.ApplicationServices);
```

now you can access it like

```
using (var connection = AppStatics.SqlConnections.NewFor<LoginLogRow>())
```